# Targeting Regex for specific content

Tags: html, regex

I want all data of Hometown: 
How do i enchance this regex

```
Hometown: ([^<]*) <br>
```

to get all the Hometown: fields.
Currently it will take first and stops in there, wont continue to next Hometown: field

Some sample inputs:

```
    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/94613582">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>
    BIS: 94613582 <br>
    Hometown: MONTREAL <br>


    <div class="hori"></div>

    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/046251945">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>
    BIS: 046251945 <br>
    Hometown: ALABAMA <br>


    <div class="hori"></div>

    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/041634545">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>
    BIS: 041634545 <br>
    Hometown: GEORGIA <br>


    <div class="hori"></div>

    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/487915646">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>
    BIS: 487915646 <br>
    Hometown: FLORIDA <br>


    <div class="hori"></div>

    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/165875487">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>
    BIS: 165875487 <br>
    Hometown: KANSAS <br>
```

Comment: Must you use regex? It's not always a good idea ([e.g. this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1364007)) when you could, say, parse the XML.

Comment: What do you want to capture? Please provide the sample output you want to get from the input you already supplied.

Comment: I want only the strings. Montreal, Alabama, Georgia, Florida, Kansas

Answer (score 1):

Here you are, you need to find the string "Hometown", then capture the name itself into a capturing group, and then only use this first group **and to match them all you should use `/g` modifier with `exec` method**:

```js
var re = /Hometown: ([^<]+)\s/g; 
var str = '<strong><a href="/search/company/company/94613582">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>\n    BIS: 94613582 <br>\n    Hometown: MONTREAL <br>\n\n\n    <div class="hori"></div>\n\n    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/046251945">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>\n    BIS: 046251945 <br>\n    Hometown: ALABAMA <br>\n\n\n    <div class="hori"></div>\n\n    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/041634545">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>\n    BIS: 041634545 <br>\n    Hometown: GEORGIA <br>\n\n\n    <div class="hori"></div>\n\n    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/487915646">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>\n    BIS: 487915646 <br>\n    Hometown: FLORIDA <br>\n\n\n    <div class="hori"></div>\n\n    <strong><a href="/search/company/company/165875487">Anchor sample Ltd</a></strong><br>\n    BIS: 165875487 <br>\n    Hometown: KANSAS <br>';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += "<br>" + m[1];
}
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

In case the space is optional after the city name, use

```
var re = /Hometown: ([^<]+)(?=\s*<)/g;
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oE8bW2/1)

Answer (score 0):

'g' modifier should be set.

The g modifier is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

Comment: How to do it, for this line Hometown: ([^<]*)   im pretty new with regex